# List of distinct types without casting to common superclass

Tags: c#, types

How do I store objects in a list, but have them retain their original type? Without being casted to their common superclass.

So that the below code can work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Super>()
        {
            new Type1 { Number = 1, Info = "infomatin" },
            new Type2 { Number = 2, Prop = "propty" }
        };
        foreach (var t in list)
        {
            Doer.Do(t);
        }
    }
}

public class Super
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class Type1 : Super
{
    public string Info { get; set; }
}

public class Type2 : Super
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }
}

public static class Doer
{
    public static void Do(Type1 arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Got type 1 with {arg.Info}");
    }

    public static void Do(Type2 arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Got type 2 with {arg.Prop}");
    }
}
```

Wanted output:

```
Got type 1 with infomatin
Got type 2 with propty
```

Actual output, compiler error:

```
Test.cs(15,21): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Super' to 'Type1'
```

---

I could do this inside the `foreach`

```
if (t instanceof Type1)
    Doer.Do((Type1) t);
else if (t instanceof Type2)
    Doer.Do((Type2) t);
```

But I don't want to have to write so much code. Especially as I add more subclasses of `Super`.

I would like to have to add only an additional method to my `Doer` to handle the new type, then the rest is taken care of.

Comment: Then you  may use reflection ... because this is not how polymorphism  works

Comment: Could you not implement `Do` as a virtual/abstract method in `Super` and then override it in each subclass?

Comment: @SBFrancies that's a good idea. I'm not sure why I'm averse to that or if it's sensible. Atm Type1, etc., they're all models and don't have any methods. Just collection of properties. `Do` uses them against other objects I don't know if it's appropriate for them to have knowledge of. Because they were method-less models, collection of properties representing a real world thing, and felt p clean and segregated, I didn't feel completely comfortable adding the `Do` method on them directly.

Comment: Is it important, that the  `Do(..)` methods are distinct methods per sub type - that handles each sub type in its own way, or is it just a matter of different properties on the sub types?

Comment: @HenrikHansen well, the different properties are what's most important... but they are properties of the subtype, nicely encapsulated

Answer (score 3):

You can use pattern matching, with only one `Do()` method

```
public static void Do(Super arg)
{
    switch(arg)
    {
        case Type1 t1:
            Console.WriteLine($"Got type 1 with {t1.Info}");
            break;
        case Type2 t2:
            Console.WriteLine($"Got type 2 with {t2.Prop}");
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

As far as avoiding *casting*, I feel you have misunderstood how `C#` works. When you store in a base class, the memory contents are still the of the derived class and there is not casting in the sense of copying data from one type to another

This type of operation does not involve any data copy

```
Super obj = new Type1();
```

Neither does this

```
Type1 t1 = (Type1)obj;
```

It just the reference `t1` putting on a different "mask" than `obj`, and the data behind the mask is the same.

**Edit 1**

A any casting (of the form `(type)value` in C#) is cast that might include a conversion or not. Some examples where `obj` is if type `object`, `sup` is of type `class Super`, `t1` is of type `class Type1 : Super` and `t2` is of type `class Type2 : Super`.

- No conversion, or identity casts

  - `obj = sup;`
  - `sup = t1;`
  - `sup = t2;`
  - `sup = t1; t1 = (Type1)sup;`
  - `obj = t1; sup = (Super)obj;`
  - `obj = t1; sup = (Type1)t1;`

The code below requires the following custom conversion code to be added to `Type1` and `Type2` respectively.

```
public static implicit operator Type1(Type2 t2) => new Type1() { Info = t2.Prop };
public static explicit operator Type2(Type1 t1) => t1.Info.StartsWith("prop") ? new Type2() { Prop = t1.Info } : throw new NotSupportedExpection();
```

- Implicit Conversion casts (data copy, may fail)

  ```
   {   // Implicit conversion Type2 -> Type1
       object obj = new Type2() { ID = 2, Prop = "propval" };
       Type1 t1 = (Type2)obj;
   }
  ```
- Explicit Conversion casts (data copy, may fail)

  ```
   {
       // Explicit conversion Type1 -> Type2
       object obj = new Type1() { ID = 1, Info = "propInfo" };
       Type2 t2 = (Type2)(Type1)obj;
   }
  ```

<sub>Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions. for more accurate information.</sub>

Comment: What's the name for "putting on a different 'mask'"? Isn't it exactly "upcasting"? I chose to call that casting in my question... I didn't think that was wrong...

Comment: @minseong - sorry the correct terminology is _casting but without conversion_ as opposed to _casting with conversion_ which is more memory and CPU intensive. I may have muddled the issues in my answer. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If you find yourself using switch/case and casting, there's a good chance you're doing it wrong. With a properly designed object model, it shouldn't be necessary.

For example

```
abstract public class Super
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public abstract void Do();
}

public class Type1 : Super
{
    public string Info { get; set; }

    public override void Do()    
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Got type 1 with {this.Info}");
    }
}

public class Type2 : Super
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }

    public override void Do()    
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Got type 2 with {this.Prop}");
    }
}
```

Now you can just do this in your loop:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<Super>()
    {
        new Type1 { Number = 1, Info = "infomatin" },
        new Type2 { Number = 2, Prop = "propty" }
    };
    foreach (var t in list)
    {
        t.Do();
    }
}
```

The above is consistent with [Tell, Don't Ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) which is a traditional object-oriented philosophy.

If you are worried about separation of concerns (for example, you don't want your classes to have knowledge of "Console") then you can inject the external functionality:

```
abstract public class Super
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public abstract void Do(Action<int> action);
}

public class Type1 : Super
{
    public string Info { get; set; }

    public override void Do(Action<int> action)    
    {
        action(this.Info);
    }
}

public class Type2 : Super
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }

    public override void Do(Action<int> action)    
    {
        action(this.Prop);
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<Super>()
    {
        new Type1 { Number = 1, Info = "infomatin" },
        new Type2 { Number = 2, Prop = "propty" }
    };
    foreach (var t in list)
    {
        t.Do( x => Console.WriteLine("The value that we're interested in is {0}", x));
    }
}
```

There is one more situation which may apply here (based on your comments). Let's say you have "clean" DTO objects that have no methods, and you don't want to add any for whatever reason, e.g. maybe the DTOs are code-generated and you can't modify them. This is actually a common situation (I like methodless DTOs too).

To make the situation more real, let's use more meaningful examples. Let's say you have a variety of objects that might contain an end user's name, but with various different identifiers:

```
abstract public class Super
{
}

public class Type1 : Super
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Type2 : Super
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

The temptation here is to write a switch case like this:

```
foreach (var t in list)
{
    switch (t)
    {
         case Type1 type1 : Console.WriteLine("Name is {0} {1}", type1.FirstName, type1.LastName);
         case Type2 type2: Console.WriteLine("Name is {0}", type2.FullName);
         default:
             throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

The problem here is that runtime `throw`, which will occur any time someone adds a different object type but doesn't remember to update your `switch` statement. This might not be a problem, but it also might be a huge problem, e.g. if your DTOs are held in a separate library from your `Do` processor and you would rather not have to update both at the same time (which could be a deployment concern under certain architectures).

What is missing here is a business concept of "Name" agnostic of where it came from. Somewhere, some code has to translate these various objects into something that has a name, and preferably that logic would be encapsulated somewhere.

That's where I would use an adapter class.

```
class NameHolder
{
    public string FullName { get; }

    public NameHolder(Type1 type1)
    {
        this.FullName = type1.FirstName + " " + type1.LastName;
    }

    public NameHolder(Type2 type2)
    {
        this.FullName = type2.FullName;
    }
}
```

With the addition of this missing business concept, the logic become very simple:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<NameHolder>()
    {
        new NameHolder(new Type1 { Number = 1, Info = "infomatin" }),
        new NameHolder(new Type2 { Number = 2, Prop = "propty" })
    };
    foreach (var t in list)
    {
        Do(t.FullName);
    }
}
```

Notice the lack of `throw`. The advantage of this approach is that all types are resolved at compile time, so if you forget to add logic to map the proper fields, you will get a compile time error, which you can detect and fix immediately.

Comment: Atm Type1, etc., they're all models and don't have any methods. Just a nicely-encapsulated collection of properties. `Do` feels "external" to me, it processes another object using information contained within Type1, Type2. I don't know if it's appropriate for these simple models to have knowledge of the other objects. Because they were method-less models, collection of properties representing a real world thing, and felt p clean and segregated, I didn't feel completely comfortable adding the Do method on them directly. What do you think?

Comment: @minseong That is a valid concern. I've edited my answer to share my thoughts.

Comment: This is a really incredible answer and I've learned a lot from it, thank you for your kindness in taking so much time to detail all this. I'm going to have to experiment with my codebase to see if I can switch to using an adapter class easily, I'll wait a while before coming back.